# how can i do sessions in java if some one disables cookies in my browser?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, cookies

I like to know if someone disables the cookies in my browser then cookies dont work for my browser then how can I do sessions in java. I am writing servlets for server side programming.
Then how does my sessions work? How does it recognize the user? As JSESSION ID is stored in cookies...

Comment: There are various methods, as some of the answers show. An important question is - How secure should it be? If it's a blog, not very. If it's banking, a lot more. That really influences the solution.

Comment: There are not various methods. There's only one method: encode/rewrite the URL to include (some sort of) session ID. There are no other ways. It's secure enough as long as you don't leak the URL to others. For banking you can always add one more check based on the `user-agent` and/or `remote-attr` headers and tie it to a specific session.

Comment: Are we still relying on these techniques of URL rewriting or Cookies?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

See HttpServletResponse [encodeURL()](http://java.sun.com/products/servlet/2.2/javadoc/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#encodeURL(java.lang.String)) and [encodeRedirectURL()](http://java.sun.com/products/servlet/2.2/javadoc/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#encodeRedirectURL(java.lang.String)).

These functions will rewrite your URLs appropriately to include the session information if the browser doesn't support cookies.  Depending on what Java web framework you're using, these functions may be called automatically (as long as you use the framework's methods for writing URLs).

Note that this may not be desirable in all cases, due to the security and caching implications of making the session ID visible in the links.  [This page](http://randomcoder.com/articles/jsessionid-considered-harmful) summarizes the issues much better than I can in this short space, and provides a way to disable this feature.

Answer (score 6):

You need to append the `jsessionid` to all the URL's involved in your webapplication which are supposed to be invoked by the **client**. This includes the redirect URL's and the links in the JSP page.

In case of a redirect URL, you need to use [`HttpServletResponse#encodeRedirectURL()`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#encodeRedirectURL%28java.lang.String%29) first:

```
response.sendRedirect(response.encodeRedirectURL("page.jsp"));
```

In case of links in a JSP page, you basically need to pass those URL's through  [`HttpServletResponse#encodeURL()`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#encodeURL%28java.lang.String%29) first. You can do this with help of [JSTL](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/)'s (just drop [jstl-1.2.jar](http://download.java.net/maven/1/jstl/jars/jstl-1.2.jar) in `/WEB-INF`) [`<c:url>`](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/url.html) tag, it will behind the scenes pass the URL through the aforementioned method:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
...
    <a href="<c:url value="page1.jsp" />">link1</a>
    <a href="<c:url value="page2.jsp" />">link2</a>
    ...
    <form action="<c:url value="servlet" />" method="post">
        ...
    </form>
```

Answer (score 2):

If cookies are disabled, you can still maintain sessions by sending the value of JSESSIONID as a query parameter, like:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/somePage?JSESSIONID=389729387392
```

Keep in mind that if security is a primary concern then you may not want to use this approach, as it puts the session id right into the url.

Answer (score 2):

For reference, it's good to know that html5 introduces `sessionStorage` as part of [Web Storage](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/). There is a good article on 24ways.org introducing it: [Breaking Out The Edges of The Browser](http://24ways.org/2009/breaking-out-the-edges-of-the-browser).

Support:

- Latest: Internet Explorer, Firefox, Safari (desktop & mobile/iPhone)
- Partial: Google Chrome (only supports `localStorage`)
- Not supported: Opera (as of 10.10)

[HTML5 (including next generation additions still in development)](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/)

Comment: people who disable cookies most likely will disable those too.

Comment: As you can read in https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=341524 the browsers already may disable the storages automatically when cookies are disabled.

Answer (score 1):

If cookies are disabled, most session providers append a URL parameter called JSESSIONID to maintain session state

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, you servlet container, e.g. tomcat,  automatically resorts to putting the JSESSIONID in the url if the browser doesn't allow cookies. It is configurable in tomcat, as you can see in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436752/supporting-sessions-without-cookies-in-tomcat).

My advice is that you simply try it. Take your web application as it is right now, without changes, and run it in your browser with cookies disabled, and see what happens.

Comment: The linked answer is wrong. The `cookies="false"` will **permanently disable** the use of cookies to maintain the session and it will **not** automatically rewrite the URL for every request. It will only do so for plain vanilla GET requests (and thus not for POST requests). And still then, you have to change all links in your page to include URL rewriting.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are great; I don't need to repeat that. But I do have some additional comments.

Please don't put session data (the entire session) in a cookie, but only a session id, possibly hashed. It's way too easy for people to edit the contents of a cookie. Leave the session data on the server; possibly in a database if you have lots of concurrent users or sessions live very long.

If even the session id itself is very precious you could even put it in a POST parameter, thereby preventing that it occurs in the URL itself.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the standard taglibs for JSP-pages, notably the `<c:url>` tag.

http://onjava.com/pub/a/pub/a/onjava/2002/05/08/jstl.html?page=2

I believe that it also handles the jsession-id attribute if cookies are not available.