# How to implement cookies with GWT?

Tags: gwt

I have this LoginController in my gwt application which is use to access a login service:

```
service.connect(username, password);
```

Once the service succeeds it updates the user model:

```
model.setCredentials(username, password);
```

There is a model change listener which fetches other user data from the server when the credential is set, when the gwt application is logged in.

However, my issue is that the login is not persistent, that is the user has to log-in for every tab that is opened.

How can I implement a cookie on my gwt application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a cookie after login using [Cookies](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/Cookies.html) class, method `setCookie`. Then after switching tabs check if cookie is set.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't sound like cookies make sense, if two tabs shouldn't share the same session. Instead, consider some other way of identifying the session to the server, such as appending to the url (see [Supporting Sessions Without Cookies in Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436752/supporting-sessions-without-cookies-in-tomcat)), or not using j2ee sessions at all, but having each request authenticate (or offer a token that was received on the first auth).