# cannot get getCurrentUser() after ajaxSuccess

Tags: android, grails, spring-security

after i done with this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40284283/login-from-android-http-post-to-grails-3-spring-security/40309422?noredirect=1), and i already add my code into `application.groovy` like this

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = [
[pattern: '/',               access: ['permitAll']],
[pattern: '/error',          access: ['permitAll']],
[pattern: '/index',          access: ['permitAll']],
[pattern: '/shutdown',       access: ['permitAll']],
[pattern: '/assets/**',      access: ['permitAll']],
[pattern: '/**/js/**',       access: ['permitAll']],
[pattern: '/**/css/**',      access: ['permitAll']],
[pattern: '/**/images/**',   access: ['permitAll']],
[pattern: '/**/favicon.ico', access: ['permitAll']],
[pattern: '/login/ajaxSuccess',       access: ['permitAll']],
[pattern: '/login/ajaxSuccess/**',       access: ['permitAll']],
[pattern: '/**/ajaxSuccess/**',       access: ['permitAll']]
```

]

my error log become [like this..](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByvgNTv5gx2dbDdTLUNlWnBvWVU)

this is corporateUserService.groovy file

```
def getCurrentCifUser() { //line 949
def cifUser = CifUser.find("from com.vastpalaso.app.cif.CifUser cu where cu.userDetails.user.id=?", [
                    springSecurityService.principal.id //line 950
            ])

            return cifUser
        }
```

and this is in logincotroller..

```
def cifUser = corporateUserService.getCurrentCifUser() //line 168
```

Comment: can you share the code in CorporateUserService.groovy:950 and LoginController.groovy:168? Btw, this will be deprecated in future versions, please refer to: https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-core/commit/daeeb700b7de1820efa4d2da0b1f4a81bea5adad

Comment: @RobertoPerezAlcolea see my updated post

Comment: I don´t see the usage but if you´re using `springSecurity.getCurrentUser()` you will retrieve a `User` instance. Please see https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-core/blob/daeeb700b7de1820efa4d2da0b1f4a81bea5adad/grails-app/services/grails/plugin/springsecurity/SpringSecurityService.groovy#L77

`getCurrentUser()` makes a call to the database. Assuming that `cu` is the result of `getCurrentUser()` you should be able to do `cu.id`. `def cifUser = CifUser.find("from com.vastpalaso.app.cif.CifUser cu where cu.id=?", [springSecurityService.principal.id])`

Comment: yes,, i must retrieve user instance, but acctually i dont get it, thats why i am getting null object on thiis line `println "cifus = "+cifus`

Comment: you have   springSecurityService.principal.id //line 9 again as I said you need to cahnge that to username and then get the user from User.findByUsername(principal)

Comment: @vahid i already change it to username, i get _grails.anonymous.user_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing like 950 segment to :

```
def getCurrentCifUser() {
                def cifUser = CifUser.find("from com.vastpalaso.app.cif.CifUser cu where cu.userDetails.user=?", [
                                springSecurityService.currentUser
                ])

                return cifUser
        }
```

Now going back to your [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40284283/login-from-android-http-post-to-grails-3-spring-security/40309422?noredirect=1)

How about you change your [HTTPURLConnection to be more like this](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/security/51092-spring-security-authenticating-from-java-client-with-http-connection) on the android app:

```
public class BasicAuthenticationExample {

    public static final String URL_SECURE = "[secure url]";
    public static final String URL_LOGOUT = "[logout url]";

    private HttpClient client = null;

    /**
     * Constructor for BasicAuthenticatonExample.
     */
    public BasicAuthenticationExample(String host, int port) {
        client = new HttpClient();

        List<String> authPrefs = new ArrayList<String>(2);
        authPrefs.add(AuthPolicy.DIGEST);
        authPrefs.add(AuthPolicy.BASIC);
        client.getParams().setParameter(AuthPolicy.AUTH_SCHEME_PRIORITY, authPrefs);
        client.getParams().setAuthenticationPreemptive(true);
        client.getState().setCredentials(new AuthScope(host, port, AuthScope.ANY_REALM),
                new UsernamePasswordCredentials(ConnectionConstants.USERNAME, ConnectionConstants.PASSWORD));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BasicAuthenticationExample example = new BasicAuthenticationExample("localhost", 8080);

        // create a GET method that reads a file over HTTPS, we're assuming
        // that this file requires basic authentication using the realm above.
        GetMethod get = new GetMethod(URL_SECURE);

        // Tell the GET method to automatically handle authentication. The
        // method will use any appropriate credentials to handle basic
        // authentication requests. Setting this value to false will cause
        // any request for authentication to return with a status of 401.
        // It will then be up to the client to handle the authentication.
        get.setDoAuthentication(true);

        try {
            // execute the GET
            int status = example.client.executeMethod(get);

            // print the status and response
            System.out.println(status + example.client.getState().toString() + "\n" + get.getStatusLine()
                    + get.getResponseBodyAsString());

            example.logout();
        } catch (HttpException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            // release any connection resources used by the method
            get.releaseConnection();
        }
    }

    private void logout() throws HttpException, IOException {
        // create a GET method that reads a file over HTTPS, we're assuming
        // that this file requires basic authentication using the realm above.
        System.out.println("Logging out...");
        System.out.println("--------------");
        GetMethod get = new GetMethod(URL_LOGOUT);
        try {
            // execute the GET
            int status = client.executeMethod(get);

            // print the status and response
            System.out.println(status + client.getState().toString() + "\n" + get.getStatusLine()
                    + get.getResponseBodyAsString());

        } finally {
            // release any connection resources used by the method
            get.releaseConnection();
        }
    }

}
```

[Also a point of reference here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15096764/implementing-spring-security-with-java-client)

Comment: as i know `org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;`already deprecated